# Yocto bitbake ninja: command not found

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I am following the Yocto Project 2.4.2 Quick Start guide, word for word and it fails when I try to build for the Intel MinnowBoard. I am doing the build on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in Virtual Box. I did everything twice to be sure and tried the systemd DefaultTasksMax workaround. I also installed ninja.

Is 2.4.2 too new and unstable? What version should I be trying out?

The following start guide command fails, leading to a mismatched git repository.

```bash
~/Yocto/poky/meta-intel$ git checkout tags/8.0-rocko-2.4.2 -b meta-intel-rocko-2.4.2
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'meta-intel-rocko-2.4.2' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'tags/8.0-rocko-2.4.2' which can not be resolved as commit?

bitbake core-image-base
...
| nm -D -u src/boot/efi/systemd_boot.so | grep ' U ' && exit 1 || :
| x86_64-poky-linux-objcopy -j .text -j .sdata -j .data -j .dynamic \
|   -j .dynsym -j .rel -j .rela -j .reloc --target=efi-app-x86_64 src/boot/efi/systemd_boot.so systemd-bootx64.efi
| /home/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-intel-common-poky-linux/systemd-boot/234-r0/temp/run.do_compile.26622: line 120: ninja: command not found
| WARNING: /home/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-intel-common-poky-linux/systemd-boot/234-r0/temp/run.do_compile.26622:1 exit 127 from 'ninja src/boot/efi/linux${SYSTEMD_BOOT_EFI_ARCH}.efi.stub'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command in the quick start guide:

```
$ git checkout tags/8.0-rocko-2.4.2 -b meta-intel-rocko-2.4.2
 Switched to a new branch 'meta-intel-rocko-2.4.2'
```

Should be changed to:

```
~/poky/meta-intel$ git checkout -b meta-intel-rocko-2.4.2  origin/rocko
Branch meta-intel-rocko-2.4.2 set up to track remote branch rocko from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'meta-intel-rocko-2.4.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have master of poky and rocko of meta-intel checked out. Make sure to check out the same branch in each repo.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did the following steps per the quick start guide: $ cd ~/poky
     $ git checkout -b rocko origin/rocko

Comment: I am trying a new build using the same repo (hopefully). Although meta-poky does not report any repo.
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "rocko_2.4.2:342fbd6a3e57021c8e28b124b3adb241936f3d9d"
meta-intel           = "meta-intel-rocko-2.4.2:90d32d53cf2d0d7b0edc5e8eab734f620fb8c3ec"